# How to select search result in vim

Tags: gvim

I am having many search results highlighted. While moving to everyone of them I want to visually select each search terms.

I have the following URLs in the whole file. I want to get the `id_11169` part and replace the whole thing with `11169.jpg`

```
/ImageVault/Images/id_11169/width_320/height_240/aspectRatio_1.3333/compressionQuality_80/scope_0/ImageVaultHandler.aspx
```

should become

```
11169.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this sample command work for you?

> echo "/ImageVault/Images/id_11169/width_320/height_240/aspectRatio_1.3333/compressionQuality_80/scope_0/ImageVaultHandler.aspx" | sed 's|(id_[0-9]*).*|\1.jpg|g'

Would translate to the following vim command,

```
:%s/\(id_[0-9]*\).*/\1.jpg/g
```

Or, maybe you want just the basename, try this,

```
:%s/.*\(id_[0-9]*\).*/\1.jpg/g
```